# Sprite inside DataGrid

Tags: actionscript-3, datagrid, sprite

I have a DataGrid (listDataGrid) on stage, with DataProvider (listDataProvider) as source. I want to be able to add Sprites into one of the DataGrid's columns, which would change color depending on where the mouse is clicked.

I have a separate class to handles CellRenderer, and to add data from a static MovieClip class (present in library before run time). However, I have no clue how to achieve the same kind of functionality for dynamic content.

Edited:
According to flash docs, CellRenderer can also be a type Sprite. As such, I was looking around to see if I can create a DataGridColumn to render a Sprite that I create at run time.

My code looks like this:

```
import fl.data.DataProvider;
import fl.controls.DataGrid;
import fl.controls.dataGridClasses.DataGridColumn;
import flash.display.Sprite;

var newBox:Sprite = new Sprite;
newBox.graphics.beginFill(0);
newBox.graphics.drawRect(0,0,20,20);
newBox.graphics.endFill();

var dp:DataProvider = new DataProvider;
var _testDataGrid:DataGrid = testDataGrid;
testDataGrid.rowHeight = 20;
_testDataGrid.dataProvider = dp;
var colA:DataGridColumn = new DataGridColumn("A");
var colB = new DataGridColumn ( "sprite" ) ;
colB .cellRenderer = Sprite;
colB .dataField = "sprite";
_testDataGrid.addColumn(colA);
_testDataGrid.addColumn(colB);

dp.addItem({A:"test", sprite:"newBox"});
```

This results in a following error:

```
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.
        at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChild()
        at fl.controls::DataGrid/drawList()
        at fl.controls::DataGrid/draw()
        at fl.core::UIComponent/callLaterDispatcher()
```

Have no clue where to take it from here :x

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
dp.addItem({A:"test", sprite:newBox});
```

i.e. no quote marks